# Adding attribute entries in combobox in QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am developing a QGIS plugin which contains 2 combo boxes:

1. comboBox
2. comboBox_2

combobox lists the vector layers available, however I would like the 2nd combobox_2 to list the all names available in  attribute column 'names' (from the attribute table).
After debugging following code I can select leyers from combobox but combobox_2 not working for selecting names.

```
    def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = GetMapDialog()     
    # Fetch the currently loaded layers
    layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()
    self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
    self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()
    # Populate the comboBox with names of all the loaded layers
    self.dlg.comboBox.addItems([layer.name() for layer in layers])

    selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex].layer()
    fieldnames = selectedLayer.fields() 
    features = selectedLayer.getFeatures()
    dist =[]
    for field in fieldnames:
        if field == 'names':
            for feature in features:
                dist.append(feature)
        else: pass
            
     self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()
     self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItems(dist)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend very strongly to consider using a custom QGIS widget for your layer combo box. Instead of a generic `QComboBox`, you can use a `QgsMapLayerComboBox`. This custom widget will load automatically all layers loaded in the current project, however you can easily filter these to only show polygon layers using:

`self.dlg.comboBox.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)`.

It will also handle behind the scenes any case where layers are added or removed from the project, even while your plugin dialog is open, so you don't need to worry about connecting to signals emitted by the project and re-populating your generic combo box.

In a Windows OSGeo4W install, in the bin folder, you will find a batch file called qgis-designer or qgis-ltr-designer.

[image]

This batch file will open Qt Designer with all the QGIS custom widgets available. I suggest to open your `.ui` file, delete the `QComboBox` and replace it with a `QgsMapLayerComboBox` as in the screenshot below.

[image]

Then you can edit your `plugin.py` file and copy the code below. Note that I have created one additional method, `populate_combobox_2()`, and connected it to the `layerChanged` signal of the `QgsMapLayerComboBox`, so that the Name combo box (comboBox_2) is updated whenever the layer selected in the layer combo box changes.

You will also need to add the following line to the imports at the top of the file:

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerProxyModel
```

Other section of `.py` file which will populate your combo boxes:

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""

    # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
    # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = GetMapDialog()
        # Connect signal to slot which will update comboBox_2 whenever selection in comboBox changes
        self.dlg.comboBox.layerChanged.connect(self.populate_combobox_2)
    self.dlg.comboBox.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)
    self.populate_combobox_2()
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()


def populate_combobox_2(self):
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()
    selectedLayer = self.dlg.comboBox.currentLayer()
    if selectedLayer:
        self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItems(sorted([i for i in selectedLayer.uniqueValues(selectedLayer.fields().lookupField('names'))]))
```

Example result:

[image]